# How to get max of subseries in Pine script

Tags: finance, pine-script

Lets suppose we have series of numbers. It contains some values `[..., 3, 6, 4, 7]`. I would like to get maximum of 100 last elements.

I tried `max(series[100])`, but it looks like series[100] operator returns sub-series discarding last 100 elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's correct. In Pine-script **everything** become a series, even a constant once you are using it, since all functions return a `series`. This means, that you can always put (non-series) constants *in*, but you can never get them *out*.

I think what you want is:

```
//@version=3
study("Max of N", shorttitle="max", overlay=false)
nmax = highest(n, 100) // n is the series of ALL bars
plot(nmax, style=line)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer. Is it possible to get highest of last n candles without current bar (closed only)? And what about skipping weekend candles?

Comment: @Jan Those are two different questions. Just search for them here first, and if there are no such questions then make sure to ask them in it's own separate question.

Comment: @Jan: in Pine everything is a series. `close` is a series, and `close[1]` is a series as well, that is just shifted 1 item and start from `[1]`. As `close[1]` is a series in itself, and you can have the previous value from a series by using index `[1]`, it is perfectly valid to write this: `price_val = (close[1])[1]`.